# How to use order function to order negative value?

Tags: r, negative-number

I am trying to use `order` function to order a column of the table,

```
a<-c("-2","-7","-4")
b<-c("9","-1","3")


z<-data.frame(a,b)
```

When I want to order Z by column a, from the largest to smallest, while it doesn't work. The function orders the negative value by its absolute value.

```
z[order(z$a,decreasing=TRUE),]
```

Comment: When I try this I get z order either in decreasing or increasing values for column a.  This seems to work.  Can you post the order you would like to see the data and the order that you are seeing the data?

Comment: do you really mean for `a` and `b` to be factors? I'm guessing that is leading to the counter intuitive results.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to convert factors to numeric you must, as the FAQ describes, first convert to character tna then to numeric:

```
 str(z)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: Factor w/ 3 levels "-2","-4","-7": 1 3 2
# $ b: Factor w/ 3 levels "-1","3","9": 3 1 2

z[order( as.numeric(as.character(z$a)), decreasing=TRUE ), ]
   a  b
1 -2  9
3 -4  3
2 -7 -1
```

(Explanation: Factors, unless of course they are "ordered factors", are *not* ordered and comparisons with ">" or "<" will return NA.

```
> z$a[1] > z$a[2]
[1] NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(z$a[1], z$a[2]) : > not meaningful for factors
```

What is being ordered in your effort was the internal coercion to numeric which was not as you expected. )

```
> z$a
[1] -2 -7 -4
Levels: -2 -4 -7
> as.numeric(z$a)
[1] 1 3 2
```

Comment: `z[order(a)]` still works as expected. -2,-4,-7 - largest to smallest. Or is it just that it's correct by coincidence?

Comment: Apparently that wasn't the order the OP was expecting. He didn't actually say what he expected. I was assuming the he was bothered by the difference in text collation order of "negative numerics" as characters versus numbers:  "-2" > "-7"
[1] FALSE;   -2 > -7
[1] TRUE

Comment: `z[order(a)]` only works because you have the `a` variable which is a vector of characters. When we put that in a data frame it becomes a factor and you need to convert it. It coincidentally does what you want because it reads the character as dash-number, hence in sorting `"-9"` is larger then `"-1"`. Because all values are negative you get the decreasing effect, but this is just a coincidence.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple vector:

```
x <- c(2, 4, 0.5, -0.5 ,-1, 3,10) 
print(x) 
2.0  4.0  0.5 -0.5 -1.0  3.0 10.0
> order(x)
 5 4 3 1 6 2 7 # Not cool

> match(x, sort(x)) 
4 6 3 2 1 5 7 # Cool
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the original post (which contains its own example/problem that you don't mention here)? Your last line gives the same result as `rank(x)`, by the way.

Comment: `order` gives you the values that allow you to sort items in ascending ... wait for it ... "order". So it is precisely cool that the lowest item (-0.5) gets the value =1 and the highest value (10) gets the largest value =7.